# the complications in javascript node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've learned node.js and javascript lately. I loved node.js a lot, but I am working  on a  project coded in node.js, mongodb, cordova etc. I notice that I needed to use `Promise` Object in the code a lot.

I create a module in the project to query the db and bring results. In every exported function I need to declare a local function, then use promise, for example:

I have the following local functions in the Module:

```
var Initialize = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    try {
      MongoClient.connect("db_url_conn", function(err, database) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        db = database;
        return resolve(db);
      })
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  });
};
```

then in every exported function in the module I needed to use:

```
mongoOperation.prototype.getLength = function() {
  Initialize(function(db) {
    return db;
  }).then(function(db) {
    getSize(db).then(function(length) {
      console.log(length);
    });
  });
}
```

The Question is:

1. Is that normal according to the nature of node.js and JavaScript  nature to use promise a lot?
2. Do I have any other  choices to fulfill that?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's async by nature. 2. Observables?

Comment: Your second code block isn't using `Initialize` correctly. The function you're passing into `Initialize` is never called, as `Initialize` does nothing with any arguments. The `then` part is also non-optimal. Instead: https://jsfiddle.net/mp29Lvze/ (pastie.org is down).

Comment: yes , thanks  , it  was working any way  , but that wasn't the the discussion ,
we are discussing  here about the complications to get a value !!

Answer (score 2):

Since `MongoClient.connect()` already returns a promise, you can simplify your code:

```
var Initialize = function() {
  return MongoClient.connect("db_url_conn");
};
...
Initialize().then(function(db) { ... });
```

However, this will create a new client each time you call `Initialize`, where you should be reusing the client for better performance and to leverage the built-in connection pool:

```
var client = MongoClient.connect("db_url_conn");
var Initialize = function() { return client };
```

Comment: Oh, sure. I'm sorry.

Comment: @robertklep actually I did that , but when I execute other function depending on the MongoClient.connection , it threw an error , undefined , so I am  obligated to use this first to be sure that MongoClient  did the connection !!

Comment: @MohammadAbdullah I don't see how this code can return an undefined value.